# Variable passed from PHP to JS function evaluates for <p>, but not for <video> source

Tags: php, javascript, video, parameters, arguments

First of all, I need to thank this community in general for the wealth of knowledge represented here!  The answers I've found on these pages since I started trying to learn PHP & Javascript have been immensely valuable.  In fact, this is the first time that I've run up against a problem that I haven't been able to solve simply by searching here.  It's a fairly specific problem, but hopefully the answer will be useful to more than just me.

The code below is a condensed version of a much larger document, but I've boiled it down to the essential problem.  Unfortunately, it does require a video file in order to illustrate the problem; I'm not sure what to do about that.  Hopefully any interested testers will be able to substitute media files on their local servers.

The goal here is to play a movie and display 3 pictures beneath.  The source of the movie is specified by PHP, but because I need to control timing, the movie is played by calling a Javascript function.  Thanks to many previous answers here, I've learned how to pass a variable value from PHP to Javascript.  (You can tell that that much is working, since the 2nd cell of the first table row displays the correct file name.)

The problem is that despite having the correct value, the newSource argument just isn't evaluating as part of the  tag. One other user reported a similar issue in Safari 5.1 ([Safari 5.1 in doesn't allow <video> source to detect $_SESSION variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492276/safari-5-1-in-doesnt-allow-video-source-to-detect-session-variables)), but the same problem crops up for me in Chrome & Firefox as well.

Here's the code:

```
<?php session_start();?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>

            function ShowMovie(newSource){
                 document.getElementById("Movie").innerHTML="<video id='video1'><source=" + newSource + "type='video/mp4'></video>";
                 //document.getElementById("Movie").innerHTML="<video id='video1' source=" + newSource + "type='video/mp4'>"; this doesn't work either'
                 document.getElementById("Para").innerHTML="<p>" + newSource + "</p>";
            }

            function DisplayPics(){
              document.getElementById("Pic1").innerHTML="<img src=<? echo $_SESSION['pic1']?>>";
              document.getElementById("Pic2").innerHTML="<img src=<? echo $_SESSION['pic2']?>>";
              document.getElementById("Pic3").innerHTML="<img src=<? echo $_SESSION['pic3']?>>";
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="Movie">

                </td>
                <td id="Para">

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="Pic1">

                </td>
                <td id="Pic2">

                </td>
                <td id="Pic3">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <?php 
            AssignPics();
            AssignMovie("Movies/foobar.mp4");//Testers: replace this file path with any playable video.    
        ?>
        <script>DisplayPics();</script>

        <?php

        function AssignPics(){
            $_SESSION['pic1'] = "Pictures/a.jpg";//Testers: replace these image sources with any images.    
            $_SESSION['pic2'] = "Pictures/b.jpg";
            $_SESSION['pic3'] = "Pictures/c.jpg";
        }

        function AssignMovie($file){
            echo "<script>ShowMovie(" . "'" . $file . "'" . ");</script>";
            //echo "<script>ShowMovieName(" . $file . ");</script>"; //Without the added single quotes, it throws "Uncaught ReferenceError: Movies not defined."
        }
        ?>


    </body>
</html>

Thanks very much for whatever help you can give!
```

Comment: what is the html code after the php is generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the 'source' attribute in quotations... which you've also left out -- the actual attribute for the source on a source tag is 'src'... so for this line:

```
document.getElementById("Movie").innerHTML="<video id='video1'><source=" + newSource + "type='video/mp4'></video>";
```

change it to:

```
document.getElementById("Movie").innerHTML="<video id='video1'><source src='" + newSource + "' type='video/mp4'></video>";
```

Comment: Thanks for catching this; this solves the problem for the condensed code above.  Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue for the full version of my code, and I'm still trying to pinpoint the difference.  I just didn't want to hold off any longer before thanking you for this part.